# How to pass a List to RDD in Scala Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I am doing the first assignment of Big Data Analysis with Scala and Spark on Coursera. https://www.coursera.org/learn/scala-spark-big-data/programming/QcWcs/wikipedia

I got stuck at implementing the following method:

```
def rankLangs(langs: List[String], rdd: RDD[WikipediaArticle]): List[(String, Int)] = ???
```

And the List is defined earlier in the program:

```
val langs = List(
    "JavaScript", "Java", "PHP", "Python", "C#", "C++", "Ruby", "CSS",
    "Objective-C", "Perl", "Scala", "Haskell", "MATLAB", "Clojure", "Groovy")
```

My understanding is that for each element in the list, I should pass it to the RDD so that it can do the filtering and count the number of occurrence of programming languages appearin the Wikipedia articles. I am thinking to do a for loop / foreach in the RDD to loop over the list. Is it doable? If not, could you suggest what to do in order to achieve the functionality?

Here is the snapshot of the problem description: 
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwdE5.png)

My implementation of occurrencesOfLang is as follows:

```
    def occurrencesOfLang(lang: String, rdd: RDD[WikipediaArticle]): Int =
    {
        val tmp: Array[(String, Int)] = rdd.filter(line => line.text.contentEquals(lang)).map(line => (lang, 1)).aggregateByKey(0)(_ + _, _ + _).collect()
        return tmp(0)._2    
    }
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: I do not understand what exactly are you asking. If you have some solution why do you ask if it is doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for this answer.

```
def rankLangs(langs: List[String], rdd: RDD[WikipediaArticle]): List[(String, Int)] = {
    return langs.map(x=> (x,WikipediaRanking.occurrencesOfLang(x, WikipediaRanking.wikiRdd))).sortBy(_._2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tnik you are looking for something like this:

```
def occurrencesOfLang(lang: String, rdd: RDD[WikipediaArticle]): Int = {
        val wordsRdd: Int = wikiRdd.filter(_.text.contains(lang))
          .flatMap(word => word.text.split(" "))
          .filter(_.equalsIgnoreCase(lang))
          .count().toInt
        wordsRdd
      }
```

Comment: this is for the previous step:                                                                                       def occurrencesOfLang(lang: String, rdd: RDD[WikipediaArticle]): Int = {
    return wikiRdd.filter(line => line.text.toString().contains(lang +" ")).count().toInt;
  }